# Embedding the new, black YouTube player

Tags: youtube, video-player

How can I embed the new, black YouTube player into my website (the one that was just launched)?

[image]

*I've asked this before, but it was closed since nobody bothered to actually read the question before voting down and closing. No, I did not ask how to embed V2 or V3 of the player, I'm asking about the new one that was just launched.*

PS: I'm new so I don't know if someone will re-open my other question or if it will just stay closed for eternity. Feel free to delete one of the two questions, as long as the other stays open..

EDIT: If you don't know what I'm talking about, read: http://newsinabox.net/1630/youtube-launched-cosmic-panda.html

Comment: The information in [Tom Squires answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704484/embedding-the-new-black-youtube-player/6704539#6704539) was insufficient? Did it not work? Was it not what you were looking for? It seems to answer the question.

Comment: Just compare the picture in my question to the picture in the article linked to by Tom Squires. These are two completely different things. As I said, I'm not looking to embedd v2 or v3 of the player...

Comment: Also some folks are easily offended, you could have posted an image that doesn't include the words "Go screw yourself", just saying mate.

Comment: On closer inspection I do indeed see the images are not identical.

Comment: Applogies, I actually didn't even notice that. I just took the first YouTube channel that got into my mind. And I like Kurt Hugo Schneider. Seriously, I'm just asking about embedding the new player.

Comment: @Ben I just spent 20 minutes fleshing out a beautiful answer to your url regex question... but you pulled the question??? Why?

Comment: @playful I just saw this and really can't remember. Probably because no one had answered yet and I solved it myself. My apologies. This problem can be avoided by posting a short answer first and then extending it later on. Once there is an answer, the author cannot delete the question (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered to the other question. Here's how to do it: http://claudiuceia.info/article/embed-new-dark-youtube-player/

Simply add a new parameter "theme=dark" to the iframe source.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpful! :)
If anyone should need it for the js-player, its the same as for the iFrame version, just use `swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID +  "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1&version=3&fs=1&rel=0&hl=en_US&border=0&theme=dark");` with your own custom options, of course (see also http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).